# Animated images with css3

Tags: css

i have a question about css steps animation, so i have 12 images, and i want to slide this images like animated gif. But i couldn't achieve that.

My Demo : http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/9hwv565g

what i want to : http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-image-sprite-animations-with-steps-function

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wink {
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes wink {
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@keyframes wink {
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: -500px; }
}

.hi {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-image: url("http://i44.tinypic.com/nq7mrp.png");
    margin: 0 auto;

    -webkit-animation: wink .8s steps(10, end) infinite;
    -moz-animation: wink .8s steps(10, end) infinite;
    animation: wink .8s steps(10, end) infinite;
}​
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "slide like animated gif"? It looks like you currently having it sliding/looping in a way...

Comment: so i mean : http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-image-sprite-animations-with-steps-function

Comment: i guess `background-position` should be width of images, and in `steps` number of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the background-position value and the steps argument, in you case your image measures 1595px in width and has 12 frames:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wink {
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: -1595px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes wink {
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: -1595px; }
}

@keyframes wink {
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: -1595px; }
}

.hi {
    width: 133px;
    height: 126px;
    background-image: url("http://i44.tinypic.com/nq7mrp.png");
    margin: 0 auto;

    -webkit-animation: wink .8s steps(12, end) infinite;
    -moz-animation: wink .8s steps(12, end) infinite;
    animation: wink .8s steps(12, end) infinite;
}
```

**[Demo here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/jqbfh3np)**